# How to add rows based on values in another column

Tags: pandas, append

I would like to append rows based on value in another column -

```
fruit value
'grape' 1
'apple' 2
'peach' 3
```

Wanted output - I would like to append rows by *n when the value is larger than 1. `'apple'` row will be populated twice, and `'grape'` row will be populated three times

```
fruit value
'grape' 1
'apple' 2
'apple' 2
'peach' 3
'peach' 3
'peach' 3
```

Comment: `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['value']))`

Comment: I get the the message - 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

Comment: can you provide a full reproducible example (with index) as DataFrame constructor?

Comment: You can also try `df.iloc[df.reset_index().index.repeat(df['value'])]`

Comment: Is there a way not to reindex, using 'df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['value']))'? I want to preserve the previous index

Comment: can you provide a better example input as DataFrame constructor? This should already preserve the index